# How can I use a column as index to find words in another column using SparkSQL?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe just like this:

[image]

And I want to use the list of indexes from top5 to find the corresponding word in words.

For example,if in the first row, `words` is `[I ,am , a ,student, how, about, you]` and `top5` is `[5,4,0,1,2]`  Then I want a new column with word form `words` whose index is the number of `top5`, so the result is `I , am , a, how, about`.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the number of values in `top5` is fixed you can easily use bracket notation or `getItem`. Using the example from the question:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array

df = sc.parallelize([
    (["I", "am", "a", "student", "how", "about", "you"], [5, 4, 0, 1, 2])
]).toDF(["words", "top5"])
```

you can either:

```
df.select([col("words")[col("top5")[i]] for i in range(5)])
```

(no longer applicable due to change of behavior in Spark 3.0)  <s>or:</s>

```
df.select([col("words").getItem(col("top5")[i]) for i in range(5)])
```

with both giving the same result:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|words[top5[0]]|words[top5[1]]|words[top5[2]]|words[top5[3]]|words[top5[4]]|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|         about|           how|             I|            am|             a|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

If you wan an array column just wrap one of the above using `array` function:

```
df.select(array(*[
    col("words").getItem(col("top5")[i]) for i in range(5)
]).alias("top5mapped"))
```

```
+----------------------+
|top5mapped            |
+----------------------+
|[about, how, I, am, a]|
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I can provide solution in scala. I hope that helps.

I assume you have data in a dataframe called df.

```
val result = df.rdd // gives you an rdd of row 
.map { row =>
        val id = row.getString(0) // first column
        val words = row.getAs[Seq[String]]("words").toArray // second column
        val top5 = row.getAs[Seq[Int]]("top5").toArray // third column

        val requiredValues = new ListBuffer[String]() // to store the result

        top5.foreach(x => requiredValues += words(x)) // extract data for "words5" for ever value in "top5"

        (id,words,top5,requiredValues.toArray)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# prepare data =>
data = [[12345,['I' ,'am' , 'a' ,'student', 'how', 'about', 'you'],[5,4,0,1,2]],
        [12346,['And','I', 'want', 'to', 'use', 'the', 'list', 'of' ,'indexes'],[1,2,5,6,7]],
        [365464,['whose','index','to', 'the', 'number', 'of'],[4,0,2,3,1]]
       ]

def getdata(row):
    words = row[1]
    top5 = row[2]
    result = [[words[index] for index in top5]]
    return row+result

rdd.map(getdata).collect()
```